Adding a javascript file to the .Net 8.0 Blazor web assembly project
I created a new .NET 8.0 Blazor application in Visual Studio by following these steps:

Create a new project via the "Blazor Web App" template

Select "Blazor Web Assembly" as the renderer



The new project consists of client and server projects. I created a new JavaScript file in the wwwroot folder of the client project and want to call the JS file in the index.html (like what was in .NET 7.0). However, there is no index.html file in the client project; there is only an App.razor file in the server project.
How can I add the JS file to the client project?


You can add js files as before.

Hi @Samira, if you want to put the js file in cliend site project, pls check my code below.

Blazor Web App has App.razor, it is not standalone wasm app - there is no need for index.html.
If you want just wasm app - without a server, use different template (Blazor Standalone Wasm) and you will have the index.html
In Blazor Web App place the <script> tag into App.razor.

I require both server and client applications. I attempted to incorporate the 
the wwwroot directories get merged.. Does the generated html has the script tag?

yes it has a script file.

Well, what's the problem then? You have the file imported through the script tag..

Right, the problem is the script file is in wwwroot of the client project and I can't call that from "app.razor".

what do you mean by "call that"? Does it get imported in a browser?

1.Place the js file in xxx.client project:

2.Create the razor component Index.razor
@page "/Index"
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

<h3>Index</h3>

Welcome to your new app.
@using Microsoft.JSInterop

<h3>Welcome to Blazor</h3>
<button @onclick="ShowAlert">Show Alert</button>

@code {
    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
    private IJSObjectReference module;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
                "import", "./test.js");
        }
    }
    private async Task ShowAlert()
    {
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("showAlert", "Hello from Blazor!");
    }
}

